# Operation must use an updateable query ASP Query Failing

Tags: sql, ms-access, iis, asp-classic

Below is the error code I am receiving after running an Update query

`2015-02-18 17:30:12 192.168.2.240 GET /webinsert.asp Date=02/10/2015&Field=38|443|80004005|Operation_must_use_an_updateable_query. 80 - Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko - 500 0 0 56`

I recently moved the database from one server to another. I can read the data no problem. It has proper IIS User rights (read and write). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some code will help you get an answer.

Comment: What specifically do you need? This also worked on a previous server so I know that my code at least works on another setup. I'm assuming it is permission errors given the error code `80004005` and the `Operation_must_use_an_updateable_query` error.

Comment: See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168?wa=wsignin1.0) for a good list of potential causes of this error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure your IIS user has write permissions to the .mdb file **and** the folder containing the .mdb file (`/wwwroot/db` in your case based on your comment). The folder requires write permission because Access creates an .ldb file in the same folder to handle database locking.

Also from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/175168?wa=wsignin1.0):

> You may also need to give read/write permission on the "Temp" folder
>   because Jet may create temporary files in this directory.

I assume they are referring to C:\Windows\Temp but I'm not positive.

Comment: My IIS_IUSRS account has Modify, Read & Execute, Read, and Write permissions. It is also the same thing for the actual database file. Is there another account or additional permissions that need to be set?

Comment: @Jim See the edit to this answer. Also see my comment to your question above.

Comment: Adding the IIS_IUSRS account to the temp directory (in the same folder as the db folder, and the windows folder) did not work, but I did add the IUSR account to the database folder and this fixed the issue I was having.

Comment: @Jim What is your "database folder" and how is that different from the folder containing your .mdb file?

Comment: I have a "db" folder in the same directory as the "wwwroot" folder

Comment: @Jim That's the folder I was referring to. I updated my answer to make it clearer. I'm glad it helped.

Comment: The IUSR account was key. Thanks @Jim