# Multiple active sessions with ASP Classic login

Tags: session, asp-classic

I have a simple login script in ASP Classic.

When the login is successful it creates a session variable for the user to be identified with.

However, when one user is already logged in, another cannot login. They will receive an error saying "You must use an updatable query."

Should I create unique session cookies for each login? I'm not too sure... Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" action="" name="login_form" class="login_form">
      <div class="login-wrap">
        <h1>login</h1>
        <p><%=error%>
        <p><input type="text" name="login_user" id="login_user" placeholder="user"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" placeholder="password"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn"></p>
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
```

ASP:

```
// Process login 
if request.form("login_user") <> "" then
   user = Request.Form("login_user")
   password = Request.Form("login_pass")

   set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   conn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=******;User ID=Admin;" & _
   "DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("contacts.mdb")
   set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE user=" & user
   rs.open sql, conn

   if rs.EOF then
      error = "Sorry, your user was not found."
   end if

   if Request.Form("login_user") = "" then
      error = "You must enter your user number."
   elseif Request.Form("login_pass") = "" then
      error = "You must enter your password."
   elseif rs("pass") <> "" then
      if password = rs("pass") then
         session("id") = rs("area")
         session("user") = rs("user")
         Response.Redirect("admin.asp")
      else
         error = "Invalid password."
      end if
   else
      error = "Please enter a password."
   end if

   rs.Close
   conn.Close
   set rs = nothing
   set conn = nothing 
end if
```

Comment: Just to check, is each user in the contacts table unique? The way you do the search is seems like there is a small chance of having multiple users with the same name. If users are only unique by their user and pass combination you may need to continue stepping through the rs. When you just check your result count for each test value do you only get 1 count?

Comment: @Kheaney Thanks for the response. The users are unique. The only value that has the potential to replicate is stored in session("id"), which has a 1/4 chance of being the same. But user is unique. If I run rs.RecordCount it retrieves -1...

Comment: Can you explain how you are testing that another user cannot log in? are you using different computers? browsers?

Comment: If you use `rs.open sql, conn, 3,1` this should solve the recordcount issue.  (Read about cursor types if you want to understand why.)

Comment: This is a common permissions problem with Access db files. See [Operation must use an updateable query ASP Query Failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28711037/operation-must-use-an-updateable-query-asp-query-failing/28724386#28724386)

Comment: True. You make a good point. Ok thank you very much @halfer.